# VBA - Conditional Formatting for Specific Sheets and Spefiic Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to loop through 3 sheets that update daily and format each of them based on different conditions. I've been getting several errors with the below section, such as Run-time error '91'.

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, String:="=REPAIR"
```

Please refer to the comments in the code below.

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim condition1 As FormatCondition, condition2 As FormatCondition, condition3 As FormatCondition, condition4 As FormatCondition, condition5 As FormatCondition

   Set ws1 = Sheets("sheet1")
   Set ws2 = Sheets("sheet2")
   Set ws3 = Sheets("sheet3")

        ' Format Conditions for Sheet1
        '   - Check column AZ for all available rows (starting on row 6)
        '   - If Cell Value = "REPAIR" or "REPAIR - INSUFFICIENT HOLDINGS" or "OTHER" highlight the row RED
        '   - If Cell Value is blank, highlight the row YELLOW
        With Range(ws1.Cells(2, 52), ws1.Cells(1000, 1))
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="REPAIR - INSUFFICIENT HOLDINGS"
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="REPAIR - REFER NARRATIVE"
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="OTHER"
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=" "

            With .FormatConditions(1)
                .SetFirstPriority
                .Font.Color = vbRed
            End With

            With .FormatConditions(2)
                .SetFirstPriority
                .Font.Color = vbRed
            End With

            With .FormatConditions(3)
                .SetFirstPriority
                .Font.Color = vbRed
            End With

            With .FormatConditions(4)
                .SetFirstPriority
                .Font.Color = vbYellow
            End With
        End With

        ' Format Conditions for Sheet2
        '   - Check column N for all available rows (starting on row 2)
        '   - If Cell Value = "OTHER" or "INSUFFICIENT", highlight the row RED
        '   - If Cell Value is blank, highlight the row YELLOW
        'With Range(ws2.Cells(2, N), ws2.Cells(1000, 1))

        'End With

        ' Format Conditions for Sheet3
        '   - Check column CC for all available rows (starting on row 2)
        '   - If Cell Value = "OTHER" or "AWAITING CP", highlight the row RED
        '   - If Cell Value is blank, highlight the row YELLOW
        'With Range(ws2.Cells(2, CC), ws2.Cells(1000, 1))

        'End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen good point. I originally had a loop that went through all worksheets and an if statement to check for worksheet names. Disregard the loop - i'll remove it from above

Comment: Also, [`FormatConditions.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.add) doesn't have a `String` parameter...

Comment: @BigBen would I then simply need to get rid of the String operator and leave "=TEXT"

Comment: `String` should be `Formula1`, and get rid of the `=` within quotes. Though I'm not sure what the last condition is supposed to be.

Comment: And you have set the format for the 2nd through 4th conditions you've added.

Comment: @BigBen gotcha. It looks like it is formatting correctly. Refer to edited code above. I'm still curious on how I can have the whole row be highlighted, rather than the single cell

Comment: Then you'd need an actual formula, not text.

Comment: @BigBen so, rather than having *Type:=xlCellValue*, I changed it to *Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="$AZ6="REPAIR""*